# knockoutJS + master page/view

Tags: mvvm, master-pages, knockout.js

Doubt this is possible as I don't have a 1 page app, but pretty much every view I make contains 80% of the same css/javascript, so is there any way I could tell knockoutJS a master view which everything else would just populate?

I doubt it as this is pretty much what a 1 page app is for... best I can hope for is to use something like Combres to combine all my non-changing stuff together into one resource file per type...

== EDIT ==

Adding example of what I mean, I am pretty sure I wouldn't be able to inject into multiple areas like shown below, but here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Master Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/Styles/main.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/Styles/Themes/simple.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/Styles/jquery.qtip.min.css">
        {Per Page Css Here}
    </head>
    <body>
        {Per Page Content Here}

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Libs/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Libs/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Libs/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Libs/jquery.qtip.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Libs/knockout-1.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Libs/knockout-external-templates.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Libs/cufon-yui.js"></script>

        {Per Page Scripts Here}
    </body>
</html>

<!-- View 1 -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/Styles/Views/view1.css">
<h1>Some Content</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/view1.js"></script>

<!-- View 2 -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/Styles/Views/view2.css">
<h1>Some Other Content</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/view2.js"></script>
```

Again, if I cannot do this its not a game breaker, just dont want to have to update every view if I update the jquery version etc...

Comment: Why do I keep finding someone called @Will editing my questions, but they dont actually seem to do anything (other than change mvvm to mvc, which is the wrong pattern for knockoutjs), is there a badge for it or something?

Comment: you should post a question on meta.stackoverflow.com for complaint.

Comment: cba complaining, just rather annoying. I dont mind people editing my stuff if i type nonsense, but just editing for editing sake is silly...

Comment: My bad, MVVM is 99% of the time the MVC pattern adapted to WPF.  Didn't know it is also associated with KnockoutJS.  Should probably put a note about that in the tag wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare your Javascript code relevant to each view in your views and the common code in your master page. Then call that bit of code from your master page and bind them using `ko.applybindings`.

Comment: could you give me a REALLY quick example of what you mean, as that sounds like a 1 page app approach... but if its not this may be exactly what I want

Comment: Can you add up small code snippet from your app and the portion which you are unsure where to add. It will also help us get an idea of your exact situation.

Comment: added example to top, I dont need to be able to inject into multiple sections, but it would be awesome if I could... as I hate having Css/Js includes littered throughout...